# IBM watson のtext to speechを利用してWindows上で日本語の音声ファイルを作成する方法（テキスト：日本語→音声：日本語）

Tags: windows, cmd

IBM watsonを参考にWindowsのコマンドプロンプトを使用して、日本語のテキストを変換して日本語の音声ファイルを作成し、再生したいと考えています。日本語のテキストを変換して日本語の音声ファイルを作成するコマンドを教えていただきたいです。

使用したコマンドは下記の通りです。

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:APIKEY" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: audio/wav" --data "{\"text\":\"東京\"}" --output sample.wav "URL/v1/synthesize?voice=ja-JP_EmiVoice"
```

生成されたsample.wavにはテキストで次の内容となっていました。

```
{ "error": "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 9: invalid start byte", "code": 400, "code_description": "Bad Request" }
```

Comment: どのように再生しようとなさったのかを質問文を [edit] して追記いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: エラーが発生しその内容が`sample.wav`に書き込まれていませんか？ テキストエディタ等で内容を確認してください。とりあえずコマンドプロンプトで実行した場合、日本語文字列がShift-JISエンコーディングになるため、Watson側が理解できないように思います。

Comment: @sayuri 様　ご回答ありがとうございます。テキストエディタでは下記の通りに表示されました。
{
   "error": "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 9: invalid start byte",
   "code": 400,
   "code_description": "Bad Request"
}
今回、Windowsのコマンドプロンプトでは日本語の音声ファイルを作成することはできないのでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 様　ご返信ありがとうございます。追記いたしました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WindowsのコマンドプロンプトはANSI（日本語版ではShift-JIS）エンコーディングを使用します。より正確にはプロセス起動側がANSI / Unicodeどちらでも選べて今回のcmd.exeはUnicodeを使用します。起動されたプロセスもANSI / Unicodeどちらも選べますが、今回のcurl.exeはANSIを選択します。
そのため、 `--data "{\"text\":\"東京\"}"` とした場合にShift-JISエンコーディングのバイト列がcurl.exeに渡されます。

curl.exeで行うためにはコマンドライン引数を使うのではなく、UTF-8エンコーディングで作成したファイルを渡すのが確実でしょうか。お手数ですがメモ帳で

```
{"text":"東京"}
```

という内容のファイルを作成しUTF-8で保存してください。 `--data @ファイル名` を指定すれば期待する動作をするのではないでしょうか。

---

しかし、質問には「コマンドプロンプトを使用して」とあります。メモ帳が介在するのは期待しない手順かと思います。この場合、PowerShellを使用するのが確実です。

```
PS> $json = ConvertTo-Json -Compress @{text = "東京"}
PS> $bytes = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($json)
PS> $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "APIKEY" -AsPlainText -Force
PS> $cred = [PSCredential]::new("apikey", $pass)
PS> Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Credential $cred -ContentType application/json -Headers @{Accept = "audio/wav"} -Body $bytes -OutFile sample.wav -Uri URL/v1/synthesize?voice=ja-JP_EmiVoice
```

残念ながら割といろいろ書く必要があって大変です…。

Answer (score 0):

IBM Watson 用の SDK が提供されています。

[Client library to use the IBM Watson services in Python and available in pip as watson-developer-cloud](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk#watson-developer-cloud-python-sdk)

これを利用して python script を書いてみました。

###### インストール

```
C:\Users\nemo\Documents>python -V
Python 3.9.7

C:\Users\nemo\Documents>pip install ibm-watson
```

###### text2speech.py

```py
import sys
from ibm_watson import TextToSpeechV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

TEXT_TO_SPEECH_IAM_APIKEY = '...'
TEXT_TO_SPEECH_URL = 'https://api.au-syd.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/...'
VOICE = 'ja-JP_EmiVoice'
ACCEPT = 'audio/wav'
OUTPUT = sys.argv[2]

auth = IAMAuthenticator(TEXT_TO_SPEECH_IAM_APIKEY)
service = TextToSpeechV1(authenticator=auth)
service.set_service_url(TEXT_TO_SPEECH_URL)

word = sys.argv[1].encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()).decode('utf-8')
with open(OUTPUT, 'wb') as af:
  response = service.synthesize(word, accept=ACCEPT, voice=VOICE).get_result()
  af.write(response.content)
```

###### 実行

```
C:\Users\nemo\Documents>python text2speech.py "隣の客はよく柿食う客だ" kaki.wav
```

※ WAV はサイズが巨大なので MP3 形式に変換しています

```html
<video height="100" controls>
<source type="audio/mp3" src="data:audio/mp3;base64,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">
</video>
```